# What is a good wireless usb lan adapter for xubuntu 10.04 and works with usb 1.0?

Tags: wireless, usb, xubuntu, adapter

Hello everyone I wanted to know if you guys know of a good wirelles usb internet adapter. I want to access the internet, but I can't because the desktop is to faraway from my router. To make things short I want to help my parents get internet in their old gateway desktop. Is there any usb wireless internet adapter that works out of the box for xubuntu 10.04? I don't have internet and don't want to drag the desktop to my room to install the drivers for usb adapter I just want it plug and play. If it supports wpa even better.

Answer (score 1):

My TP-LINK work great for me up until the 11.10 realese you may find problems there if you are thinking to going to 11.10 but with the version your on ubuntu auto detected it and allowed you to join wireless networks. And even better, Its fast.

http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WN821N

But you might want to look at something like this

https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/penguin-80211g-usb-wireless-network-adapter-w-linux-gnu-support

Comment: So this will work with xubuntu 10.04 out of the box. No I'm not planning to update is just for my parents to connect to the internet. It should support usb 1.0 rite?

Comment: Yes as far as I know it should work out of the box as it did for me with Ubuntu, Xubuntu is very simmilar so you shouldn't have any problems. And check the Websites specs to see if it supports 1.0, it should though